# linq function fails on type conversion

Tags: linq

I have a linq query with a comparison of `varchar` to `int`

```
soemthing = Lookups.Where(Function(lookupToSearch) lookupToSearch.ServiceFeature = 
CONST_ServiceFeature_EventLog And _ 
lookupToSearch.Name = CONST_ActivityTypeLookup_Name And _
lookupToSearch.Value = type.ToString()).FirstOrDefault.EntityKey
```

`lookupToSearch.Value` is `varchar`
`type` is an `enum`

some of the values in `lookuptosearch` are letters and they fail to convert to `int`.

What is the best way to solve this problem, given that I can't change the data that is mixed letters and numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but from your code, I guess that the data type of "type" variable is not supported on the database, nor it's conversion to string. So my recommendation would be to cast the type var to string before querying the database, and compare lookupToSearch.Value to the string variable representing type.ToString().

```
Dim str as String
str = type.ToString()
soemthing = Lookups.Where(Function(lookupToSearch) lookupToSearch.ServiceFeature = 
CONST_ServiceFeature_EventLog And _ 
lookupToSearch.Name = CONST_ActivityTypeLookup_Name And _
lookupToSearch.Value = str).FirstOrDefault.EntityKey
```

Comment: That worked thanks. I tried in line ToString() like lookupToSearch.Value = type.ToString() which returned an error. Something about null object.